# Specialize a visitor for types under a namespace

Tags: c++, variant, visitor-pattern

I have a variant which can contain 8 different types, some of them under a particular namespace

```
std::variant<T0, T1, T2, ns::T0, ns::T1, ns::T2> v;
```

There exists a free function which can be called with any of these types and I am visiting the variant like this

```
int function(T0 t){return 0;}
int function(T1 t){return 1;}
int function(T2 t){return 2;}

namespace ns {
template <typename T>
int function(T t) {return 3;}
}

void doSomething() {
    std::visit([](const auto &t) {return function(t);}, v);
}
```

However, now I want the user to be able to provide his own visitor and call that, and in case, the provided visitor doesn't match for the variant type, use the default one. To do so I have tried the following

```
int function(T0 t){return 0;}
int function(T1 t){return 1;}
int function(T2 t){return 2;}

namespace ns {
template <typename T>
int function(T t) {return 3;}
}

struct DefaultVisitor
{
    template <typename T>
    int operator()(T t) const {return function(t);}
}

template <typename VisitorT>
void doSomething() {
    std::visit(overloaded{VisitorT(), DefaultVisitor()}, v);
}
```

If the `VisitorT` provides a call operator for only one type, this works fine, but if it provides a call operator for several types, such as a generic lambda, then it doesn't compile.

How could I provide a VisitorT which is used by the types in the `ns` namespace, but not for other types?

https://godbolt.org/z/zv1o4nxne

Comment: Can you provide a more concrete example of what you're trying to do? "However, if the user provides a Visitor to generic, this doesn't compile" I'm not sure what that sentence means.

Answer (score 2):

You might adapt `overloaded` to have some priorities:

```cpp
template <typename T1, typename... Ts>
struct ranked_overloaded : T1, ranked_overloaded<Ts...>
{
    template <typename... Us>
    auto operator()(Us&&... args)
    {
        if constexpr (requires{ T1::operator()(std::forward<Us>(args)...); }) {
            return T1::operator()(std::forward<Us>(args)...);
        } else {
            return ranked_overloaded<Ts...>::operator()(std::forward<Us>(args)...);
        }
    }
};

template <typename T1>
struct ranked_overloaded<T1> : T1
{
};

template <typename...Ts>
ranked_overloaded(Ts...) -> ranked_overloaded<Ts...>;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vWYb6hGxc)

There is no ways to know for sure that type belongs to a specific namespace, but there is a trick which might be used to know if a type allow to found function via ADL (so types inheriting from `ns` type, or `std::vector<ns::T0>` would pass that check)

```
namespace ns
{
    template <typename T>
    void is_found_by_ADL_in_ns(T&&); // Declared only in that namespace
                                     // No definition needed.
}

constexpr auto ns_lambda =
    [](const auto &ns_obj)
    -> decltype(is_found_by_ADL_in_ns(ns_obj), /*return type of the lambda*/)
    {/*..*/};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/MGvjMj5Ed)

Comment: I am not sure this completely solve the issue. For objects that doesn't belong to the ns namespace, I still want the DefaultVisitor to be called.

Comment: If your first overload just handles type from namespace `ns`, then second overload (`DefaultVisitor`) will be used. If your question is to have traits to limits to types from specific namespace, ask another question.

Comment: Yeah, but that means that I have to provide an overload which can handle all the types in the namespace. What happens if I have 100 types in the namespace? Would be nice to be able to have a generic functor for things in the namespace. If I have to write all the overloads, then I can simply provide free functions and they will be picked before the generic functor, no need for the ranked_overload

Comment: Can you clarify your problematic case? your sample compiles. I already have to guess than you wanted to change your last lambda to a generic one; but it seems not enough.

Comment: I want to define a generic lambda or functor that can accept only types in the namespace. I have 100 types in my namespace, I dont want to define a function for each of those. "If the VisitorT provides a call operator for only one type, this works fine, but if it provides a call operator for several types, such as a generic lambda, then it doesn't compile." I think it is clear what I want, no need to guess

Comment: My code works for generic lambda, but your new problem is to create a generic lambda accepting only types from one namespace. You can so SFINAE your lambda.

Comment: Well, that is what is asked on the question, how to do that

Comment: @jjcasmar: generic lambda added which SFINAE on types "from" `ns` namespace.

Comment: That solution looks really nice. Just to mention, the ns_lambda must be defined, as you did, outside the namespace. Otherwise, all the types will be able to match. Thanks